# Save images from URLs in a form via php

Tags: php, image, forms, url, save

I have a php script which grabs an image from an external URL, reads it and saves it into a directory on my server. The script is located in a php file and contains :

```
<?php 
$image_url = "http://example.com/image.jpg"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
$timeout = 0; 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

// Getting binary data 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 

$image = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 

$f = fopen('/home1/path/public_html/path/saved/image.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);
?>
```

Everything works great there...

What I would like to do is have the script do it for multiple URLs. The URLs would be written in a form textarea, separated by comas (or else).

A submit button would then tell the script to do the trick with all the URLs in the form and save them with whatever name, it's not important (random would do fine).

I'm still a newbie, and I'm learning PHP.

Thanks in advance for your help !

**EDIT**

My code looks like this now :

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$image_urls = explode('\n', $_POST['urls']); 



foreach ($image_urls as $image_url) {
$ch = curl_init(); 
$timeout = 0; 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 

  $image = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch); 

  $f = fopen('/home1/path/public_html/path/saved/'.rand().time().".jpg", 'w');
  fwrite($f, $image);
  fclose($f);

}
?>
```

It works only for the first one, and doesn't return any errors... Any ideas ?

Thanks for your great help !

Comment: Storing individual urls in a txt or db?

Comment: Storing in a textarea, divided by lines...

Comment: Sorry i totally overlooked the problem. Somehow i thought you want to fetch these images via a cron job.

Comment: Well I might like to do that later but for now I'm just trying to do that only... Any ideas on my problem ?

Comment: Do you mean how to fetch them via a cron job?

Comment: I mean the problem described above... With this script, it only fetches the first item, and I have no idea why it doesn't process the second item. Maybe there's something to do in my code ? It must be quite easy but as I said, this is new to me :)

Comment: You have an accepted answer. Why do you edited your question then? Why do you accepted it as correct when it isn't?

Comment: Hehe I forgot, cause I thought it worked, and actually it did only for one... Unchecked ! Sorry about the misunderstanding... Do you have an idea about the solution to my tiny problem ? :)

Comment: What happens when you do `print_r($image_urls);`?

Comment: Oh, yeah I get only one item ([0]), with the two URLS in it separated by a space... Why doesn't it explode it ?

Comment: Have you pressed an enter between them?

Comment: Yes I did... What else could I use to separate them as this appearently did not work ?

Comment: Actually, the problem was that I used `''` instead of `""`. The script works !!! Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: It's hard to believe but it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the urls from a text-area and then loop over that:

```
<?php 
$image_urls = explode('\n', $_POST['urls']); # Will create a list of urls, if each line contains one url.

#Basic settings and initializers need to be ran only once. 
$sequencer = 1;
$timeout = 0;

foreach ($image_urls as $image_url) {
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image_url); 
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); 

  // Getting binary data 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 

  $image = curl_exec($ch); 
  curl_close($ch); 

  $f = fopen("/home1/path/public_html/path/saved/image_$sequencer.jpg", 'w');
  fwrite($f, $image);
  fclose($f);
  $sequencer++;
}
?>
```

Obviously, you should clean out, validate and doublecheck the inputted information: not only to avoid Goatses, but also to avoid entries that break your application (such as white lines).

Comment: Great thanks for your fast answer ! One more thing, in the HTML, I should set the action to "MYSCRIPT.php", and name the textarea "urls" right ?

Comment: Yes, method="post" action="myscript.php" with a textarea  "urls" Be aware that anyone (also those without access to the code that renders the textarea) can send a POST with a list of urls. You may want to check for access first in above-mentioned code.

Also, see Hassan's answer for further improvements: putting such a saver in a function makes better code, more readable, better maintainable and less bug-prone.

Comment: So I tried with your solution, and when I put two urls in the textarea on different lines, I get a file called image_1.jpg, with a weight of 0kb. And that's it. Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong ? Thanks !

Comment: Ok, now it works, but it does it for the first url only... Thoughts ?

Comment: I changed the code: there was a mistake in closing-opening the curl-resource. For future: try debugging and investigate logs. The logs would have told you the problem here. Debugging would have shown you why the problem occured. Sprinkle some `var_dump()` over your code. Like a `var_dump($image_urls)` just after your created that, to see if it is a correct list of urls (Array).

Comment: I did, as I said in the comment on my post... Do you know why it doesn't split them right ? I could try to separate them with comas, and then write `$image_urls = explode(',', $_POST['urls']);`right ?

Comment: A comma is an allowed character in an URL, so separating by such characters will break on some (valid) images.

Comment: Could I use something else to separate them ?